# Burninate [pie-chart]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[pie-chart](/questions/tagged/pie-chart) is an uneeded tag that yeilds many questions that have to do with many **many** chart implemetations.

As does [bar-chart](/questions/tagged/bar-chart) and [...chart](/questions/tagged/...chart) (any other "chart" tag).

[image]